# how to set action.auto_create_index via docker-compose for ElasticSearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, yaml

I have this config in docker-compose.yml:

```
  elasticsearch-node1:
    profiles: ["local"]
    image: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.2"
    container_name: elasticsearch-node1
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=mycluster
      - node.name=node1
      - action.auto_create_index=true
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch-node2,elasticsearch-node3  # Add node3
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=node1,node2,node3  # Add node3
    ports:
      - "9201:9200"
```

my internet search says that:

```
      - action.auto_create_index=true
```

is not valid.

1. is it valid?
2. if not, how to set that value via docker-compose.yml?

(Ultimately I am just trying to tell ES to auto-create any index if it doesn't already exist.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a perfectly valid setting that enables [index auto-creation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.11/index-management-settings.html) when a new document comes in for an index that doesn't exist yet. Not sure where you found that it wasn't valid.

You can add that setting in the environment section along with the other settings:

```
environment:
  - action.auto_create_index=true 
  - cluster.name=mycluster
  ...
```